# Matlab genetic algorithm tolerance

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to solve a timetabling problem using genetic algorithm.
After few generations the genetic algorithm stops and i get the following message:

```
Optimization terminated: average change in the penalty fitness value less than options.TolFun 
and constraint violation is less than options.TolCon.
```

I did some search and from what i understand it has something to do with the function tolerance:

> "The algorithm stops if the average relative change in the best
>   fitness function value over MaxStallGenerations generations is less
>   than or equal to FunctionTolerance"

which is a positive scalar.
Is there is a way to disable this option for the GA?
as we want it to continue trying solutions until the fitness value is zero or it reaches certain number of generations.

Comment: It is possible indeed. I always run GAs in Matlab and the stopping criteria is a maximum number of generations. Can you please post the code for your call to `ga()`? I'm pretty sure one of your input is `options`, that is the output for `gaoptimset()`, if that's the case can you provide also the `options` structure?

Comment: here is the options and call to ga():
    options=gaoptimset('PlotFcn'{@gaplotbestf,@gaplotscores},'TolFun',0,'PopulationSize',4000,'Generations',100000,'Display','iter');
the call:
    [x,fval]=ga(ObjectiveFunction,nvars,[],[],[],[],LB,UB,[],IntCon,options)

Comment: I reckon you can avoid the problem by doing either setting `TolFun` to `-inf` or setting a new parameter `StallGenLimit` (or `MaxStallGenerations` I reckon in your case...I'm using Matlab R2015b) as the number of generation itself. It will be almost impossible of a small change (under threshold) considering all fitness values for all generations. As instead, if you want to put a threshold on the fitness functions add the `FitnessLimit` option and set it as `0` (I'm not that sure about the `FitnessLimit` though since, again, I always let my GA reach a maximum number of generations)

Comment: Thanks for your help,
when i set `TolFun` to `-inf` i get the following error:
`The field 'TolFun' must contain a non negative scalar.`, 
but i tried setting `StallGenLimit` to  the number of generations and it is working fine till now.

Comment: Yes yes, my bad. `TolFun` cannot be negative. The `StallGenLimit` should do the trick though because it will not consider the default 50 generations, but will consider all of your 100000 generations when evaluating `TolFun`. In 50 generations over 100000 it might happen that the fitness does not change and the algorithm halts but, of course, it will not happen over 100000 generations.

Comment: Yes, now i understand the idea :D ,
Thanks.